# How to make scrolling LinearLayout android:background="@drawable/imagesliding"

Tags: android

I have LinearLayout with background image as bellow code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/imgscrolling"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:background="@drawable/bg" />
```

My purpose is to scroll LinearLayout background from Image1 to Image2...etc
Please advice me how to do it, i do appreciated..

Comment: you are scrolling background image? may be you can add gesture detector and onswipe change the background from Image1 to Image2

Comment: Yes, can you please give me some solution?

Comment: Can you explain more precisely what you exactly want? Do you want to make the LinearLayout scrollable or change its Background dynamically?

Comment: Imran,<br /> I want the background of LinearLayout is dynamical.. I mean the background is auto scrolling from image1 > image2 > images3 > image1..like this

Answer (score 0):

you can change the image in onFling method

public class SwipeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

```
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /* ... */

    // Gesture detection
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
    gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    };

}

class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            // right to left swipe
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Toast.makeText(SelectFilterActivity.this, "Left Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Toast.makeText(SelectFilterActivity.this, "Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Dear  Mahesh<br /> thanks you very much it's help me alot. I will keep this script for my picture album swip to scrol image. but I still need the script of LinearLayout backgroudimages can be auto scrolling.